# If the Kaiju are clones why do they look different?

Tags: pacific-rim

In the briefing scene when Newt is trying to convince Pentecost to support his plan he announces (in almost the same breath) these two statements:

> Kaiju Why do we divide the category system? Because each is very
>   different from to the next, right? Do you know what I mean? For
>   example, a single shark, others like fish...

and

> Here are some samples that I collected. This one was taken in Sydney.
>   This one was taken in Manila. They are exactly the same DNA. They are
>   clones.

If Kaiju (or at least various groupings of the kaiju) are clones of each other and have "exactly the same DNA" why "each is very different from to the next"?

Surely they would recognise if there were only 10 different "models" of Kaiju which were repeated over and over?

Comment: The original question is different, but [my answer](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/49568/5184) explains this. They're *not* clones. They're manufactured from cloned parts.

Comment: I think it's fair to say that the Kaiju come from somewhere that sank their R&D into genetic technology instead of electronic.

Comment: DNA isn't everything - look up epigenetics.

Comment: Your fingers and your lungs and your eyeball and your hair are all clones too.

Comment: The Kaiju are not clones in the traditional sense. They're products created from the same genetic template.